# How are the extension methods resolved after AsQueryable()?

Tags: c#

Suppose you run AsQueryable() on a collection turning into IQueryable<>
which gets two sets of extension methods because it implements IEnumerable<>

Since you can assign a single-line lambda to both Expression and Func<>,
and many extension methods have the same name, what are the compiler rules
to resolve the conflicts? It seems like the compiler assumes Expression
and whenever you want to use Func<> you have to cast the parameter explicitly to Func<>
You have to consider two cases: single-line lambda, and multiple-line lambda where 
Expression does not even apply meaning the compiler should assume Func<> 
automatically. However, the compiler always assumes Expression. Where are the rules documented?

```
List<int> grades_l = new List<int> { 78, 92, 100, 37, 81};
static public bool TWrite(int value)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Value={0}",value);
  return true;
}

// these are single-line lambdas
// Compiler assumes Expression<Func<>> and if you want Func<> then you have to cast
var all2_i3 = grades_l.All(i => TWrite(i)); // Func<>
var all2_q = grades_l.AsQueryable().All(i => TWrite(i)); // Expression<Func<>>
var all2_q2 = grades_l.AsQueryable().All((Func<int, bool>)(i => TWrite(i))); // Func<>

// these are multiple-line lambdas
// Compiler assumes Expression<Func<>> even though multiple-line lambda implies Func<>
var all2_i = grades_l.All(i => { TWrite(i); return true; }); // Func<>
var all2_i2_nc = grades_l.AsQueryable().All(i => { TWrite(i); return true; }); // fails to compile
var all2_i2 = grades_l.AsQueryable().All((Func<int, bool>)(i => { TWrite(i); return true; })); // Func<>
```